# Can't Connect to MySQL / MariaDB Database Externally

Tags: mysql, mariadb, connection, debian, external

I'm trying to connect a MariaDB client(DBeaver) to my database from my home PC. The IP Address/Host, port, the username, and password connection details are all correct.

I'm able to ping the host. The host is active. I can access the database locally on the server. I have phpMyAdmin set up for that case. However, I need to be able to externally connect for the sake of a game server I'm running on a different VPS as well.

Here's my `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` file:

```
[client-server]
# Port or socket location where to connect
# port = 3306
socket = /run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Import all .cnf files from configuration directory
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/
[mysqld]
log_warnings=1
innodb_file_per_table = ON
```

Also, here's my 50-server.cnf file:

```
#
# These groups are read by MariaDB server.
# Use it for options that only the server (but not clients) should see

# this is read by the standalone daemon and embedded servers
[server]

# this is only for the mysqld standalone daemon
[mysqld]

#
# * Basic Settings
#

user                    = mysql
pid-file                = /run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
basedir                 = /usr
datadir                 = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir                  = /tmp
lc-messages-dir         = /usr/share/mysql
lc-messages             = en_US
skip-external-locking

# Broken reverse DNS slows down connections considerably and name resolve is
# safe to skip if there are no "host by domain name" access grants
#skip-name-resolve

# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

#
# * Fine Tuning
#

#key_buffer_size        = 128M
#max_allowed_packet     = 1G
#thread_stack           = 192K
#thread_cache_size      = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
#myisam_recover_options = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64

#
# * Logging and Replication
#

# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# Recommend only changing this at runtime for short testing periods if needed!
#general_log_file       = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
#general_log            = 1

# When running under systemd, error logging goes via stdout/stderr to journald
# and when running legacy init error logging goes to syslog due to
# /etc/mysql/conf.d/mariadb.conf.d/50-mysqld_safe.cnf
# Enable this if you want to have error logging into a separate file
#log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
# Enable the slow query log to see queries with especially long duration
#slow_query_log_file    = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-slow.log
#long_query_time        = 10
#log_slow_verbosity     = query_plan,explain
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#min_examined_row_limit = 1000

# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
#server-id              = 1
#log_bin                = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days        = 10
#max_binlog_size        = 100M

#
# * SSL/TLS
#

# For documentation, please read
# https://mariadb.com/kb/en/securing-connections-for-client-and-server/
#ssl-ca = /etc/mysql/cacert.pem
#ssl-cert = /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
#ssl-key = /etc/mysql/server-key.pem
#require-secure-transport = on

#
# * Character sets
#

# MySQL/MariaDB default is Latin1, but in Debian we rather default to the full
# utf8 4-byte character set. See also client.cnf
character-set-server  = utf8mb4
collation-server      = utf8mb4_general_ci

#
# * InnoDB
#

# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
# Most important is to give InnoDB 80 % of the system RAM for buffer use:
# https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-system-variables/#innodb_buffer_pool_size
#innodb_buffer_pool_size = 8G

# this is only for embedded server
[embedded]

# This group is only read by MariaDB servers, not by MySQL.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MySQL and MariaDB,
# you can put MariaDB-only options here
[mariadb]

# This group is only read by MariaDB-10.5 servers.
# If you use the same .cnf file for MariaDB of different versions,
# use this group for options that older servers don't understand
[mariadb-10.5]
```

I've browsed around and I've edited my `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` file so that
`bind-address = 0.0.0.0`

I've also created a new user and set his host to '%' with GRANT OPTION to ensure that the user's allowed access from an external IP.

Still, to no avail, I'm not able to connect to the database.

`sudo iptables -L` returns:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-input  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:3306

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-forward  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ufw-before-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-before-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-after-logging-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-reject-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere
ufw-track-output  all  --  anywhere             anywhere

Chain ufw-after-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-after-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-logging-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-before-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-reject-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-forward (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-input (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain ufw-track-output (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

There's no firewall in place as far as I'm aware. I'm trying to currently connect to the database from my local environment, which has a dynamic IP. I'm planning on setting to be allowed from the other VPS IP solely once I get to that point.

UFW is not installed, as per a comment I tried: `sudo ufw status`

When I try connecting from my desktop, the issue that's presented is a timeout issue. As if the server's not reading/accepting an incoming connection from my IP.

I've also utilized `portchecker.co` to check port `3306` for the server's IP and it is coming back as `Closed`, even though above it shows it's LISTENING.

When trying to connect with HeidiSQL I get the error: `Can't connect to server on '1.2.3.4' (10060)` Of course, 1.2.3.4, is replaced with my server's IP.

Upon checking `netstat -tlnp | grep 3306` - it returns:
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3900555/mariadbd`

Comment: Try checking with your provider to see if there is an upstream firewall.

Comment: @user1191247 I've opened a ticket with UltaHost, will get back with a reply from them when I receive one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to go back and forth with the hosting company to get them to fix it on their end. They never gave me an exact reasoning for the problem, however through ticketing they were able to resolve the issue with the port.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).